# Why is the model loading while whereHas is false?

Tags: laravel

I have this query:

```
$result = PortingItem::whereHas('porting', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('status', [
            Porting::STATUS_REQUESTED,
            Porting::STATUS_ACCEPTED,
            Porting::STATUS_DELAYED,
        ]);
    })->where(function ($query) use ($numbers) {
        $query->whereBetween('phone_number_start', [$numbers[0], $numbers[1]])
            ->orWhereBetween('phone_number_end', [$numbers[0], $numbers[1]]);
    })->orWhere([
        ['phone_number_start', '<=', $numbers[0]],
        ['phone_number_end', '>=', $numbers[1]],
    ])->get();
```

The `PortingItem` model still returns the query result while the porting relation is empty. I don't understand why this happens.

This is my `Porting` model relation

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PortingItem::class);
}
```

This is my `PortingItem` model relation:

```
public function porting()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Porting::class);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should always group `orWhere` calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.

```
$result = PortingItem::whereHas('porting', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('status', [
            Porting::STATUS_REQUESTED,
            Porting::STATUS_ACCEPTED,
            Porting::STATUS_DELAYED,
        ]);
    })->where(function ($query) use ($numbers) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($numbers) {
            $query->whereBetween('phone_number_start', [$numbers[0], $numbers[1]])
                ->orWhereBetween('phone_number_end', [$numbers[0], $numbers[1]]);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($numbers) {
            $query->where('phone_number_start', '<=', $numbers[0])
                ->where('phone_number_end', '>=', $numbers[1]);
        });
    })->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping